# perl + perl script location under /etc/rc3.d with diff results

Tags: linux, perl, bash, ksh, sh

I need advice about the following:

**option 1**

I run the script /usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl  from /var/tmp directory in my Linux machine and there are no  problem

**option 2**

I create new script - script.pl under /var/tmp

and then I create link from /var/tmp/script.pl to /etc/rc3.d/S99script.pl  ( by ln -s )

so S99script.pl is link  to /var/tmp/script.pl

and script.pl execute the /usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl

```
 more /etc/rc3.d/script.pl 


 #!/bin/bash 


 /usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl

 .
 .
 .
```

**my problem** :

when the script bbpinstaller.pl run after reboot from /etc/rc3.d/S99script.pl then I get the following errors ( /usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl run from S99script.pl )

```
     Can't locate Term/ReadKey.pm in @INC (@INC      contains: /etc/bbp/shared /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-     64int /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/sun4-
    solaris-    64int /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/site_perl /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/sun4-    solaris-64int /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/vendor_perl
    . ) at /usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl line 25.
     BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl line 25.
```

in  /usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl script , I have  the following perl modules:

```
 #################################
 #       Modules imported
 #################################
 use Config;
 use Getopt::Long;
 use File::Find;
 use English;
 use Sys::Hostname;
 $File::Find::dont_use_nlink=1;
 use lib "/etc/bbp/shared";
 use Term::ReadKey qw(GetTerminalSize);
 use Cwd 'abs_path';
 require "bbp_globals.pl";
 require "bbp_functions.pl";
```

the PATH of the file  ReadKey.pm

```
  /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7/sun4-solaris-thread-multi/Term/ReadKey.pm
```

please help me to understand . what the problem here ??? ( I not have allot experience with Perl )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the os perl is /usr/bin/perl which has all its modules in /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/site_perl.  Since running the script via rc3 uses root's standard path and standard lib, it won't find your custom perl in /usr/local/bin and thus won't find your site-lib in /usr/local/lib.  So you need to modify your calling script "/etc/rc3.d/script.pl" which is a bash script (should probably be call script.sh but that's symantics) to include /usr/local/bin in the path, ie:  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}.  That'll pre-append the /usr/local/bin to the front of the PATH and then your perl in /usr/local/bin will be called instead of /usr/bin/perl. So change the script.pl to:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
/usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl
```

or call your script with your perl.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/perl /usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl
```

Comment: thx - good and short answer I will verify this on my linux machiine ...  soon

Comment: thx again I try option 2 and this option work fine - great answer

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/local/` is used by local installs (i.e. it wasn't provided by the OS vendor). Then your shell is setup to run (`$PATH`) /usr/local/bin/perl (5.8.7) rather than /usr/local/bin/perl (5.8.4).

However the init scripts don't run with your shell settings - they use the system settings, which won't have `/usr/local/bin` in them - so they will use the OS provided perl - `/usr/bin/perl` which doesn't have this library (`Term::ReadKey`) installed.

(The .pl extension is normally for perl programs - I'd use .sh for bash/shell scripts)

When you run a script directly (that is, not specifying an interpreter first on the command-line), the kernel uses the hash-bang line (the first line) to work out which program to execute to interpret the script.

e.g. your shell script /etc/rc3.d/script.pl has a hash bang line of "`#!/bin/bash`", telling it to execute with `/bin/bash`.

`/usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl` will have a hash-bang line at its start, possibly something like: `#!/usr/bin/env perl`

This tells the kernel/shell to look at the `PATH` variable to find an interpreter; the same way it would find `perl` if you typed it on the command-line.

In order to fix your problem, either:

1. Install Term/ReadKey into the system perl.
2. Set your PATH in you shell script as MichaelN suggests.
3. Call the explicit perl instead of letting the kernel decide, as MichaelN also suggests.
4. Recode `/usr/local/bbp/api/bbpinstaller.pl` to not need Term/ReadKey

Comment: thx but what the solution ? if I must to run the script only from /etc/rc3.d ? . what need to add or to fix or to update ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally keying off the work Douglas did in analyzing your issue, in order to provide the fix you asked for.

I would either:

1. In the RC shell script, set your PATH to run the right version of perl, and then call your Perl script.
2. Change the "shebang" line in your Perl script to use the right version of Perl.

Hope one of those helps!

Comment: thx jimtut but - maybe with example it will be more clearly , or give more details about step 1 and 2 , about the PATH you mean the PATH in my perl script ? and what you mean about the right version of perl ? , about Douglas I will wait thx allot for your support -:)